# Callback Issue Setting Variables Node

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm new to Node and still struggling through learning callbacks.  I'm trying to write a function that reads from a MySQL database and returns a single record.  I'm able to connect to the database and through logging see the values I'm expecting, but receive an error message from the last console.log that is indicating that my variable speechText is undefined. The code below is inside of a function that would need to use speechText for other things.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
var speechText;

function readRDS(params, callback){

    var connection = MySQL.createConnection({
        host     : 'myDBHost',
        user     : 'myUserName',
        password : 'myPassword',
        database : 'myDBName'
    });

    connection.connect();

    console.log("Connected to DB.");

    var SQL = params.SQL;

    connection.query(SQL, (error, result) => {  
        console.log('Result from within callback: ' + result.length);
        connection.destroy();
        speechText = result[0].Response;
        callback(); 
    });

}


readRDS(params, myResults => {
    console.log('SpeechText: ' + speechText );
});

console.log(speechText);

 //Do something with speechText here
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in node.js too but your callback is wrong in my opinion. If your input argument is myResults, then you should use it because here speechText is not initialized that's why it's not working. Try with printing myResults in your console and see what you get. You might want to call your callback with an argument (with in this case could be your result[0].Response)

Comment: Hi Remi, Thanks for the quick response.  I tried what you suggested and  the issue is that myResults is local to the callback function and I can't access it outside of the callback function.

Comment: What Rémi is suggesting is that you could pass result[0].Response as an argument to your callback. Then, in the callback, setting up the speechText value.

Comment: Thanks, laudeon.  I tried what I think you are both point out, but it didn't seem to work.  I tried passing back the result[0].Response and used it to set the speechText value.  If I log the output after that, it appears with the value, but if I add a log statement in the function that contains both readRDS and the callback, speechText is undefined.

Comment: Which is perfectly normal. It is because your call is out of the callback. The code execution is asynchronous. Thus, you cannot predict when your db query will end, and so if you log speechText without waiting the db result which means without waiting the set up of the speechText value, speechText will be empty.